# VueJS Apollo graphql store/cache data collision between queries

Tags: vue.js, graphql, vuex, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I have the following data flow scenario:

- UI has 3 sections: Enrolled Services, Enrolling Services, and
  Search Services
- User will search for existing services (upon the User
  entering searchServiceText,  searchResultServices gets called)
- The user selects a service from the search result and enrolls in a
  service. If the User's enrollment not complete (ex: no payment, not
  accepted, etc), UI will show the data in the Enrolling section.
  Otherwise, it will be in the Enrolled section

I have the following queries:

```
enrolledServices: {
 query: gql(listServices),
 variables() {
   let idFilter = this.idFilter(this.userData.enrolledServiceIds);
   return {
     filter: {
       or: idFilter
     }
   };
 },
 update: data => {
   return _.compact(data.listServices.items);
 }
},
enrollingServices: {
 query: gql(listServices),
 variables() {
   let idFilter = this.idFilter(this.userData.enrollingServiceIds);
   return {
     filter: {
       or: idFilter
     }
   };
 },
 update: data => {
   return _.compact(data.listServices.items);
 }
},
searchResultServices: {
 query: gql(listServices),
 variables() {
   console.log('before search - enrolledServices:', this.enrolledServices); //Data Collision!!
   console.log('before search - enrollingServices:', this.enrollingServices);
   return {
     filter: {
       or: [
         { name: { contains: this.searchServiceText } }
       ],
       and: [
         { status: { eq: 'Active' } }
       ] 
     }
   };
 },
 skip() {
   return !this.searchServiceText;
 },
 update(data) {
   return _.compact(data.listServices.items);
 }
}
```

1. enrolledServices: and enrollingServices: gets called on page load, hence UI will have 2 sections for enrolled services and enrolling services.
2. searchResultServices: will not be called on page load because of skip() condition. It is gets called reactively when user enters value to searchServiceText field in the UI

**Getting to my issue now**:

1. On page load as expected Service_enrolled, Service_enrolling is shown in Enrolled, Enrolling sections respectively (see below).

> **Enrolled Section**:
>
> Service_enrolled
>
> **Enrolling Section**:
>
> Service_enrolling

2. If the user sets **search word in searchServiceText and clicks search**, Enrolled section shows Service_**enrolling** (see below). User is just searching at time and he/she has not acted on the search results as yet

> **Enrolled Section**:
>
> Service_**enrolling** (enrolled service replaced with enrolling
>   service)
>
> **Enrolling Section**:
>
> Service_enrolling

**The expected behavior in step2**: I should see step 1 behavior (Service_enrolled should be in Enrolled section, Service_enrolling should be in Enrolling section) because the user has not acted on search results as yet.

Not sure why in step 2 above, there is a data collision. I have console.log to print enrolled and enrolling list in the memory/cache before hitting the search query. It shows data collision right there before hitting the search query. so search query is not contributing to the issue and there are no traces of enrolledServices, enrollingServices query execution in step 2 above. I am not sure how enrolled and enrolling data gets messed up.

Note: both enrolledServices, enrollingServices has same search query except 'idFilter' data will be different as they have different service Ids. That means, as per my understanding cache key is unique for these two queries, right?

I am absolutely sure something is missing in my approach or code but not able to figure out. Any help is much appreciated and you will save a lot of time plus for others who may have a similar issue.

Comment: TBH your explanation still left me confused as to what the desired page behavior is. The Service_A / Service_B stuff is business logic that doesn't immediately make sense to me. Can you show your entire component code to show how things are being rendered?

Comment: @LannyBose thanks for reviewing my issue. I have updated my issue with some clarification (replaced generic Service_A/B with contextual name). Hope it helps little better. I can certainly share the code but it is too large.